# How to exit from method back to a menu choice?

Tags: java, netbeans, menu

I've been working on a few projects recently and I can't seem to fully crack how to go from a menu option which takes you into a method, but then from that method return to the menu and prompt the user with the same options?

```
String userChoice = console.nextLine();

        do {
            switch (userChoice) {

                case "1":
                    enteringContacts();
                    break;
                case:"xyz"
                   }
        }while(!userChoice.equals("xyz"));
```

I've used a do While loop but instead it just repeats the method? The method "EnteringContacts" is shown below:

```
public static void enteringContacts(){

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome, How to use the system:");
        System.out.println("Enter the contacts name, then press enter");
        System.out.println("Enter the contacts number, then press enter");

        String exitContactInsert = " ";

            do {
                    contactName.add(console.nextLine());
                contactNumber.add(console.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Do you wish to add another?");
                exitContactInsert = console.nextLine();

                if (exitContactInsert.equals("no")) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter another contact");
                }
            } while (exitContactInsert.equals("yes"));

    }
```

Any help is appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you should ask user again for his choice every loop, before looping the "while" again.

add

```
userChoice = console.nextLine();
```

before line:

```
}while(!userChoice.equals("xyz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reorganize the code and to separate the logic from the user dialogs. You can provide an enum with possible actions:

```
public enum UserAction {
    EDIT_CONTACT,
    ADD_CONTACT,
    ...,
    QUIT
}
```

And for example your logic class:

```
class Logic {
    public void mainLoop() {
        while (true) {
            UserAction action = UserDialogs.getUserAction();
            switch(action) {
                case EDIT_CONTACT: 
                    editContact();
                    break;
                case ...
                case QUIT: return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you should move a responsibility of parsing entered text in options to the dedicated class with static methods:

```
class UserDialogs {
    public static UserAction getUserAction() {
        System.out.println("Select an action (1-edit, 2-add, 3-..., Q-quit):");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String response = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            switch (response) {
                case "1" : return EDIT_CONTACT;
                case "2" : return ADD_CONTACT;
                case ...
                case "Q" : return QUIT;
                default: 
                    System.out.println("Wrong selection, try again");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll be taking user response in the loop, then each iteration will be determined separately, performing different action each time until user will provide xyz.

```
String userChoice;
        do {
            userChoice = console.nextLine();
            switch (userChoice) {                
                case "1":
                    enteringContacts();
                    break;
                case:"xyz"
            }
        }while(!userChoice.equals("xyz"));
```